# Why some blocks accept parenthesized arguments in ruby?

Tags: ruby

for example:

```
{a: 1}.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), memo|

end
```

Why don't use

```
{a: 1}.each_with_object({}) do |key, value, memo|
```

And why it doesn't work with the latest version?

If you can provide links to the documetnation where this is explained.  what's the name of this, and what was the motivation to do this?